# Vectorization - negative result

Tags: python, numpy, vector

So I'm dealing with Numpy-Vectors in this little example:

```
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.time()
print('sum is: ', np.sum(np.arange(1500000)))
end = time.time()
print("duration: ", end - start)

#sum is:  -282181552
#duration: 0.0041615962982177734
```

and as you can see, I always get a negative result for adding numbers from 1 to 15x10^5.
However, when I use `for loops`, I get fine results:

```
start = time.time()
total = 0
for item in range(0, 1500000):
    total = total + item
print('sum is: ' + str(total))
end = time.time()
print("duration: ", end - start)

#sum is: 1124999250000
#duration:  0.09384274482727051
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

You get the wrong result due to an integer overflow.

By default, `np.arange()` creates arrays with a `dtype=int32` on many platforms, especially 32-bit platforms. When you add up numbers of `dtype` `int32`, you're bound by the limitations of 32-bit integer arithmetic. Once your sum exceeds [image: 2^32 - 1], it becomes negative.

The pure Python for loop doesn't have this problem because Python integers are of arbitrary precision (they don't overflow).

To fix the issue with the numpy version, you can specify a different dtype for the array:

```py
print('sum is: ', np.sum(np.arange(1500000, dtype=np.int64)))
```

This will use 64-bit integers which have a much larger range.